# Show list in browser but disable quick edit and modify

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, quick-edit

I have a list which is updated from an InfoPath form and currently its possible for the users to see and edit the list within the browser (quick edit). Is there a way I can disable quick edit but still allow the user to view the list? If I disable the ability to use quick edit in Advanced Settings it removes the list completely.
Thanks

Comment: You could create an extension to remove QuickEdit button either for a particular list or all lists.

Comment: If you are familiar with SPFX webparts, it will easy to create one. you can refer the below link to get started with extensions.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **Standard View** for displaying list items instead of using Quick Edit view (Datasheet view).

1. Create a standard view for the list.

[image]

2. Edit the page where shows the list.
3. Edit the list web part, select the view for this list web part.

[image]